# While loops in relation to alphabet characters

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to understand why this problem is occurring with my code and I am not sure how to fix this..

```
int main()
{
    char answer;
    std::cin >> answer; // valid input is a, b, c or d
    while(answer > 'd') // doesn't enter no matter what letter I input
    {
        retry(); // function call to print something long..
        std::cin >> answer;
    }
    //rest of code not shown since everything is fine after this problem;
}
```

My goal of this program is to have the user input letters a, b, c, or d and after that it will trigger a "switch' function. So I figured that I can just have a while loop that keeps asking the user to enter a valid letter if they entered one not allowed. However, it doesn't seem to work?

Problem: I want while loop to activate when a letter greater than 'd' is entered, but the loop never happens no matter what letter I input.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Test the result of formatted input ´while(std::cin >> answer) { if(answer > 'd') ... }´

Comment: my while loop I made has the goal of looping when a user enters a letter greater than d. But ti never enters the loop.

Comment: I should be adding a cin.get() to eat the newline left in input stream then sir?

Comment: Works for me. You can add a `std::cout << answer << std::endl` before the `while` loop to examine the value of `answer`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yeah, i just remembered as the different from `get`. danka. This should work unless it was turned *off* in code we're not seeing (and not part of this non-MCVE).

Comment: wait, I thought cin didn't read blank spaces.

Comment: I would think you would want to test this way:

    `while (answer < 'a' ||  answer > 'd')`

Since, for example, any capital letter has a lower ASCII value than a lower-case 'a'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some common mistakes regarding stream IO are:

1. Testing for eof
2. Ignoring the state of the stream after an extraction
3. Similar to (2), checking the result (which might not have been
   altered)

Your fail regarding 2 and 3.